# How to store values in variables with yq?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yml file, from which I am obtaining a key with yq and I am storing it in a variable in bash, I am trying to do another query with the value of the variable but it does not give the expected result

```
file.yml
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  task_auth:
    environment:
      AWS_API_VERSION: "2016-04-19"
      AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: /creds
      PORT: "8000"
      SES_AWS_ACCESS_KEY: xxxxx
      SES_AWS_SECRET_KEY: xxxxx
    image: xxxxxxx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

```
yq e '(.services | keys)[]'  file.yml
```

```
Result:
```

```
task_auth
```

Storing the query in a variable `TASK_NAME`

```
TASK_NAME=$(yq e '(.services | keys)[]'  file.yml)
```

Calling the variable to see the previously stored value

```
$TASK_NAME
```

```
bash: task_auth: command not found
```

```
yq eval '.services.$TASK_NAME.environment.PORT' file.yml
```

```
Result
```

```
null
```

if I execute the command `echo $TASK_NAME` I get the correct value `task_auth` but to make queries from yq no

Now when I need this other query I need to use the initial variable, how can I do the query using that value of `$TASK_NAME` in yq ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the Bash variable as environment variable, and inside [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) use `env` to retrieve it:

```bash
TASK_NAME="$TASK_NAME" yq e '.services[env(TASK_NAME)].environment.PORT' file.yml
```

```
8000
```

See the manual section [Read string environment variable](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Or instead of an env var, just do this:

```
project_name=$(yq .name $project_yaml)
```